# UDP packet does not arrive if not pinged beforehand

Tags: c, linux, udp, ipv6

I have a code to send a UDP datagram packet from a linux equip (server) to another (client). I have an issue when do this secuence:

1. reboot server.
2. run the program to send the packet and it is not received by the client.

if then I do a ping to the client ip, and run again the program, now the packet is received by the cliente

This is the code:

```
  int main (int argc, char **argv){
  int i, status, datalen, frame_length, sd, bytes;
  char *interface, *target, *src_ip, *dst_ip;
  struct ip6_hdr iphdr;
  struct udphdr udphdr;
  uint8_t *data, *src_mac, *dst_mac, *ether_frame;
  struct addrinfo hints, *res;
  struct sockaddr_in6 *ipv6;
  struct sockaddr_ll device;
  struct ifreq ifr;
  void *tmp;

  // Allocate memory for various arrays.
  src_mac = allocate_ustrmem (6);
  dst_mac = allocate_ustrmem (6);
  data = allocate_ustrmem (IP_MAXPACKET);
  ether_frame = allocate_ustrmem (IP_MAXPACKET);
  interface = allocate_strmem (INET6_ADDRSTRLEN);
  target = allocate_strmem (INET6_ADDRSTRLEN);
  src_ip = allocate_strmem (INET6_ADDRSTRLEN);
  dst_ip = allocate_strmem (INET6_ADDRSTRLEN);

  // Interface to send packet through.
  strcpy (interface, "usb0");

  // Submit request for a socket descriptor to look up interface.
  if ((sd = socket (PF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons (ETH_P_ALL))) < 0) {
    perror ("socket() failed to get socket descriptor for using ioctl() ");
    exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  // Use ioctl() to look up interface name and get its MAC address.
  memset (&ifr, 0, sizeof (ifr));
  snprintf (ifr.ifr_name, sizeof (ifr.ifr_name), "%s", interface);
  if (ioctl (sd, SIOCGIFHWADDR, &ifr) < 0) {
    perror ("ioctl() failed to get source MAC address ");
    return (EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  close (sd);

  // Copy source MAC address.
  memcpy (src_mac, ifr.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data, 6 * sizeof (uint8_t));

  // Report source MAC address to stdout.
  printf ("MAC address for interface %s is ", interface);
  for (i=0; i<5; i++) {
    printf ("%02x:", src_mac[i]);
  }
  printf ("%02x\n", src_mac[5]);

  // Find interface index from interface name and store index in
  // struct sockaddr_ll device, which will be used as an argument of sendto().
  memset (&device, 0, sizeof (device));
  if ((device.sll_ifindex = if_nametoindex (interface)) == 0) {
    perror ("if_nametoindex() failed to obtain interface index ");
    exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  printf ("Index for interface %s is %i\n", interface, device.sll_ifindex);

  // Set destination MAC address
  dst_mac[0] = 0x00;
  dst_mac[1] = 0x11;
  dst_mac[2] = 0x7d;
  dst_mac[3] = 0x30;
  dst_mac[4] = 0x7f;
  dst_mac[5] = 0xd0;

  // Source IPv6 address
  strcpy (src_ip, "fe80::11:7dff:fe30:8013");

  // Destination URL or IPv6 address
  strcpy (target, "fe80:0000:0000:0000:0211:7d00:0030:7fd0");

  // Fill out hints for getaddrinfo().
  memset (&hints, 0, sizeof (hints));
  hints.ai_family = AF_INET6;
  hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
  hints.ai_flags = hints.ai_flags | AI_CANONNAME;

  // Resolve target using getaddrinfo().
  if ((status = getaddrinfo (target, NULL, &hints, &res)) != 0) {
    fprintf (stderr, "getaddrinfo() failed: %s\n", gai_strerror (status));
    exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  ipv6 = (struct sockaddr_in6 *) res->ai_addr;
  tmp = &(ipv6->sin6_addr);
  if (inet_ntop (AF_INET6, tmp, dst_ip, INET6_ADDRSTRLEN) == NULL) {
    status = errno;
    fprintf (stderr, "inet_ntop() failed.\nError message: %s", strerror (status));
    exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  freeaddrinfo (res);

  // Fill out sockaddr_ll.
  device.sll_family = AF_PACKET;
  memcpy (device.sll_addr, src_mac, 6 * sizeof (uint8_t));
  device.sll_halen = 6;

  // UDP data
  datalen = 4;
  data[0] = 'T';
  data[1] = 'E';
  data[2] = 'S';
  data[3] = 'T';

  // IPv6 header

  // IPv6 version (4 bits), Traffic class (8 bits), Flow label (20 bits)
  iphdr.ip6_flow = htonl ((6 << 28) | (0 << 20) | 0);

  // Payload length (16 bits): UDP header + UDP data
  iphdr.ip6_plen = htons (UDP_HDRLEN + datalen);

  // Next header (8 bits): 17 for UDP
  iphdr.ip6_nxt = IPPROTO_UDP;

  // Hop limit (8 bits): default to maximum value
  iphdr.ip6_hops = 255;

  // Source IPv6 address (128 bits)
  if ((status = inet_pton (AF_INET6, src_ip, &(iphdr.ip6_src))) != 1) {
    fprintf (stderr, "inet_pton() failed.\nError message: %s", strerror (status));
    exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  // Destination IPv6 address (128 bits)
  if ((status = inet_pton (AF_INET6, dst_ip, &(iphdr.ip6_dst))) != 1) {
    fprintf (stderr, "inet_pton() failed.\nError message: %s", strerror (status));
    exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  // UDP header

  // Source port number (16 bits): pick a number
  udphdr.source = htons (61616);

  // Destination port number (16 bits): pick a number
  udphdr.dest = htons (61616);

  // Length of UDP datagram (16 bits): UDP header + UDP data
  udphdr.len = htons (UDP_HDRLEN + datalen);

  // UDP checksum (16 bits)
  udphdr.check = udp6_checksum (iphdr, udphdr, data, datalen);

  // Fill out ethernet frame header.

  // Ethernet frame length = ethernet header (MAC + MAC + ethernet type) + ethernet data (IP header + UDP header + UDP data)
  frame_length = 6 + 6 + 2 + IP6_HDRLEN + UDP_HDRLEN + datalen;

  // Destination and Source MAC addresses
  memcpy (ether_frame, dst_mac, 6 * sizeof (uint8_t));
  memcpy (ether_frame + 6, src_mac, 6 * sizeof (uint8_t));

  // Next is ethernet type code (ETH_P_IPV6 for IPv6).
  // http://www.iana.org/assignments/ethernet-numbers
  ether_frame[12] = ETH_P_IPV6 / 256;
  ether_frame[13] = ETH_P_IPV6 % 256;

  // Next is ethernet frame data (IPv6 header + UDP header + UDP data).

  // IPv6 header
  memcpy (ether_frame + ETH_HDRLEN, &iphdr, IP6_HDRLEN * sizeof (uint8_t));

  // UDP header
  memcpy (ether_frame + ETH_HDRLEN + IP6_HDRLEN, &udphdr, UDP_HDRLEN * sizeof (uint8_t));

  // UDP data
  memcpy (ether_frame + ETH_HDRLEN + IP6_HDRLEN + UDP_HDRLEN, data, datalen * sizeof (uint8_t));

  // Submit request for a raw socket descriptor.
  if ((sd = socket (PF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons (ETH_P_ALL))) < 0) {
    perror ("socket() failed ");
    exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  // Send ethernet frame to socket.
  if ((bytes = sendto (sd, ether_frame, frame_length, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &device, sizeof (device))) <= 0) {
    perror ("sendto() failed");
    exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  // Close socket descriptor.
  close (sd);

  // Free allocated memory.
  free (src_mac);
  free (dst_mac);
  free (data);
  free (ether_frame);
  free (interface);
  free (target);
  free (src_ip);
  free (dst_ip);

  return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: What happens when you run the program multiple times, without pinging or any other network communication? What happens if you just wait five minutes before running the program?

Answer (score 3):

It seems as if the method you have chosen to send a `UDP` packet, fails if the `dst mac` is not already in the `ARP` tables. Somehow, doing it this way, causes the kernel to not `arp` for the `dst mac` (maybe because you have manually inserted it into the packet) - BUT - the packet transmission fails nevertheless, because it doesn't exist in the `ARP` table. The `ping` causes the `ARP` table to be populated, and then it starts working.

Just a theory. We will have to look at the kernel path to confirm this.

You could try a couple of experiments to confirm this theory.

1. Don't `ping`. Run the program a few times to see if it works on subsequent runs.
2. First `ping`, then try the program (it should work), then flush the `ARP` table, try the program again (it should fail). Use `sudo ip -s -s neigh flush all` to flush the `ARP` table.

Is there any reason you are not using `SOCK_DGRAM`, which is the standard way to do `UDP`?

**EDIT**

As pointed out in the comments, I missed the fact that OP is using `IPV6`. Replace all mentions of `ARP` with `neighbor` (and equivalent).

Comment: Actually, IPv6 doesn't have ARP - it uses NDP.

Comment: True enough. Wasn't paying attention. But the theory still applies.

Comment: Yes, it does, which is why I voted +1. I just thought you may want to correct your answer for IPv6.

Comment: Thanks. Added some words.

Comment: NDP is a big improvement of ARP since ARP broadcasts and interrupts every host, but NDP multicasts to a specific group based on the last 24 bits of the IPv6 address, probably only hitting the one host for which it is trying to resolve the layer-2 address.